# Holding a CCMenuItemImage/CCMenu button for 3 seconds to trigger an action

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, cocos2d-iphone

I want to make a holding action in some cocos2d buttons of my app, in order to hold them for 3 seconds and then show the things it will bring. For Example:

```
CCMenuItemImage * menuBtnSettings = [CCMenuItemImage
                                         itemWithNormalSprite:[CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"settingsButton_over"]
                                         selectedSprite:[CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"settingsButton_down"]
                                         disabledSprite:[CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"settingsButton_over"]
                                         target:self
                                         selector:@selector(showSettings)];

    [menu addChild:menuBtnSettings z:3 tag:20];
    [menuItemsArray addObject:menuBtnSettings];
```

Is there a way for making this without affecting the whole app? Because only three buttons will have that special action.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could subclass CCMenuItemImage and override the "selected" method.

```
-(void) selected{

  isSelected_ = YES;
  if( selectedImage_ ) {
        [normalImage_ setVisible:NO];
        [selectedImage_ setVisible:YES];
        [selectedImage_ runAction:[CCSequence actions:[CCDelayTime actionWithDuration:3],[CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(makeVisibile),]nil]];

    [disabledImage_ setVisible:NO];

  } else { // there is not selected image

    [normalImage_ setVisible:YES];
    [selectedImage_ setVisible:NO];
    [disabledImage_ setVisible:NO];
  }

}

-(void)makeVisible{  
     [ selectedImage_ setVisibile:YES];
}
```

Note: I have not tested the above code. Just wanted to put across the idea